# Basic proofs for epsilon delta limits: $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{a}{1+a}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Hello I am wondering if my approach and understanding of the epsilon delta definition is correct.

For example, if I wanted to use it to show that $$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x}{1+x}=\frac{a}{1+a}$$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}, a \neq -1$

Then here are my thoughts;

I know that we want that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta$ , then $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$ for a suitable $\delta$.

My attempt:

If $|x-a| \lt a$ then $-a \lt x-a \lt a$ and $0 \lt x \lt 2a$

so $1 \lt x+1 \lt 2a+1$

so $\frac{1}{x+1} \lt 1$

and hence,

$|\frac{x}{1+x}-\frac{a}{1+a}|$=$\frac{|x-a|}{|x+1||a+1|} \lt \frac{|x-a|}{a+1}$

So then we could choose $$\delta=\min\{a,\epsilon|a+1|\}$$

and this would prove that for all $|\frac{x}{x+1}-\frac{a}{a+1}| \lt \epsilon$,

$|x-a| \lt \delta$ ?

How does this seem? Does it make sense? If there are mistakes, what should I consider?

Comment: This isn't a proof; it's some scratch notes that you might make for yourself while thinking how to set up a proof. The actual _proof_ means that you start with the assumption that $0 < \lvert x-a \rvert < \min\{a,\lvert a+1 \rvert\epsilon\}$ and step by step show facts about $\lvert \frac{x}{x+1}-\frac{a}{a+1}\rvert$, ending with the fact that this is less than $\epsilon$. You won't be able to do that, though, because $a=10$, $\epsilon=\frac{1}{10}$, $x=1$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write

> we want that for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $0 \lt |x-a| \lt \delta$ , then $|f(x)-L| \lt \epsilon$ for a suitable $\delta$.

What you actually want is: For every $\epsilon > 0$, there corresponds a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$, $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. Also, since $a$ can be zero or negative, you cannot start with the assumption $|x - a| < a$. The $\delta$ you have chosen can be negative for the same reasons.

Using the fact that

$$\frac{x}{1 + x} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + x}$$

for all $x\neq -1$, we have

$$\left|\frac{x}{1 + x} - \frac{a}{1 + a}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{1 + a} - \frac{1}{1 + x}\right| = \left|\frac{x - a}{(1 + a)(1 + x)}\right| = \frac{|x - a|}{|1 + a||1 + x|}.$$

for all $x\neq -1$. Now since $a \neq -1$, $|1 + a| > 0$. So we may consider first $0 < |x - a| < \frac{|1 + a|}{2}$. By the triangle inequality,

$$|1 + a| = |(1 + x) - (x - a)| \le |1 + x| + |x - a|,$$

thus

$$|1 + x| \ge |1 + a| - |x - a| > |1 + a| - \frac{|1 + a|}{2} = \frac{|1 + a|}{2}.$$

Hence if $0 < |x - a| < \frac{|1 + a|}{2}$, then

$$\frac{|x - a|}{|1+a||1 + x|} < \dfrac{|x - a|}{|1+a|\cdot \frac{|1+a|}{2}} = \frac{2}{(1 + a)^2}|x - a|,$$

which can be made less than $\epsilon$ by having $|x - a| < \frac{\epsilon(1 + a)^2}{2}$. So choose

$$\delta = \min\left\{\frac{|1+a|}{2},\frac{\epsilon(1+a)^2}{2}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks but how did you do the step using the triangle inequality, the one I know how to use is that we get a upper bound when we have addition, and an absolute value of absolute values for a lower bound

Comment: Sure. So you know this: $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$. Now given $x,y\in \Bbb R$, $|x| = |(x + y) - y| \le |x + y| + |-y| = |x + y| + |y|$, which implies $|x + y| \ge |x| - |y|$.

Comment: Hm right I do understand that rule, but I still am not sure how you used it exactly above.   because you have 2 individual terms in absolute values before using greater than for a second time, Could it be possible you edit to explain this part and I will accept as it does make sense

Comment: Ok, I'll make an edit in a few minutes.

Comment: I don't think you can legitimately have "for all $x\neq-1$" in the statement to be proved. I think it should simply be, "for all $x$, $0<\lvert x-a \rvert < \delta$ implies $\lvert f(x) - L \rvert < \epsilon$." You _do_ need to ensure that $x$ will not be $-1$, but the legitimate way to do that is by setting $\delta$ small enough; specifically, ensure that $\delta \leq \lvert a+1 \rvert$ (which I notice you happen to have done anyway).

Comment: Yes @David, I'll remove that part.